# Is compound assignment to bool safe?

Tags: c++, boolean, assignment-operator

I came across code like this and it made me cringe:

```
bool isEventSent = false;

if(type >= EVENT_BEGIN && type < EVENT_END)
{
    isEventSent |= m_SendToSubscribers(event);
}

return isEventSent;
```

The intent is clear, but I've never used compound assignment with bools like that and it makes me feel uneasy. Is this code safe? And if not, what would be a case it could fail?

**EDIT:**

I know that `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`, but I am wondering whether `a | b` instead of `a || b` could cause problems for booleans under some circumstances.

Comment: Please note that `|` is not the same as `||` (The second has short-circuit behaviour while the first does not)

Comment: Yes, and also (to my understanding), `||` implements boolean logic and returns a boolean value, while `|` implements binary logic and returns the product of a bitwise OR - that's what worries me.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly correct. The compound operator `a |= b` means `a = a | b`, so `isEventSent |= m_SendToSubscribers(event);` means `isEventSent = isEventSent | m_SendToSubscribers(event);`. Both individual operators (`=` and `|`) are well defined for `bool`s.

Comment: Okay, it was the "| well defined for booleans" part that I wasn't sure of. The | operator reeks too much of low-level bit twiddling to be - I felt like it could make a boolean turn up with some weird value depending on whatever values the platform uses for true and false.

Comment: @neuviemeporte To be honest, I have always written `a |= b` for booleans thinking about `a = a || b` (but without any possible short circuit behaviour)... I have never even stopped to think about the difference between `a || b` and `a | b`. Maybe I've just been lucky, because those expressions have always done what I wanted.

Comment: No, it's not "perfectly" correct. It doesn't short circuit like the boolean operators, so there are some edge cases where behavior will differ. e.g. For `a = a || b()`, `b()` may or may not be called depending on the value of `a`. But for `a |= b()`, `b()` will always be called. This can be problematic if `b()` has some side effect.

Comment: @cp.engr This doesn't mean it is not perfectly correct. It is correct, you just need to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly safe. The a |= b is mostly equivalent to doing a = a | b.